# How to insert value into a html table row by row from a popup modal using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a textbox for user input and after submit the textbox does not show the result. The textbox only show the result if I click on the textbox again. It means every time I type, the textbox shows null. After I click again the submit button, it only shows again the result.

But what I want is when I finished filled up the information, the information will automatically appear when I click the "Next"button.

Here I provide my code in jsfiddle:

```js
 $('.contactSelectDiv').off('click').click(function () {
    
   $('#contactInfoModel').openModal();

        })

  $('#btnNextContactInfoModel').click(function () {
$("body").find('input[name="email"]').val($('#contacttype').val()+ " " + " " + $('#contact').val());
   
   $('#contactInfoModel').closeModal();


   })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped">
     <h5>Contact</h5>
             <thead>
               <tr>
         <th>  </th>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Contact Info</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>

             <tbody>
             <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
                 <td>Email 1</td>
        <td>
         <div class="input-field col s12 m20 l20 contactSelectDiv">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
          </div>
           <input id="email1" name="email" type="text" readonly>
           
         </div>
        </td>
               </tr>
              <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>Email 2</td>
        <td><div class="input-field col s12 m20 l20 contactSelectDiv">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
          </div>
           <input id="email2" name="email" type="text" readonly>
           
         </div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>Email 3</td>
        <td><div class="input-field col s12 m20 l20 contactSelectDiv">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
          </div>
           <input id="email3" name="email" type="text" readonly>
        
         </div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>4.</td>
        <td>Handphone 1</td>
        <td><div class="input-field col s12 m20 l20 contactSelectDiv">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
          </div>
           <input id="handphone1" name="handphone" type="text" readonly>
           
         </div></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>5.</td>
        <td>Handphone 2</td>
        <td><div class="input-field col s12 m20 l20 contactSelectDiv">
          <div class="input-wrapper">
          </div>
           <input id="handphone2" name="handphone" type="text" readonly>
       
         </div></td>
       </tr>
           </tbody>
         </table>

<div id="contactInfoModel" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" style="max-height:100%;height:80%;width:60%;margin-left:20%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="bread-crumbs-header">
            <div class="bread-crumbs-section">
                <!--<i class="header-icon small mdi-image-hdr-weak"></i>-->
                <div class="header truncate modal-header">
                    <span data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_lookup_contact_info"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
     <select id=contacttype>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
      <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Type 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Type 3</option>
     </select>
     <label data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_type"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
      <td>Contact Info</td>
      <div id="Contact Info" >
       <input id="contact" name="contacts" type="text">
       </div>
         </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnNextContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue darken-2 right" type="button">
            <i class="mdi-navigation-check"></i>
            <span>Next</span>
        </button>
  <button id="btnCloseContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 left" type="button">
   <i class="mdi-navigation-close"></i>
   <span >cancel</span>
  </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I provide explanation of my problem in figure, too.

[Problem Explanation in Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFaNx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Here is your jquery code

```
$('.contactSelectDiv').off('click').click(function () {

    $("#storeType").val($(this).children("input").attr('id'));
    $('#contactInfoModel').openModal();
});

$('#btnNextContactInfoModel').click(function () {

    $("#contactInfoModel").closeModal();            
    $("#" + $("#storeType").val()).val($("#contact").val());
});
```

I've added one hidden filed inside your modal div, which will keep the id of an element to insert the value.

```
<div id="contactInfoModel" class="modal modal-fixed-footer" style="max-height:100%;height:80%;width:60%;margin-left:20%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="bread-crumbs-header">
            <div class="bread-crumbs-section">
                <!--<i class="header-icon small mdi-image-hdr-weak"></i>-->
                <div class="header truncate modal-header">
                    <span data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_lookup_contact_info"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 m3 l3">
                <select id=contacttype>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select</option>
                    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Type 3</option>
                </select>
                <label data-i18n="personal-particular-update.msg_type"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
                <td>Contact Info</td>
                <div id="Contact Info" >
                    <input id="contact" name="contacts" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="storeType" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="btnNextContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light blue darken-2 right" type="button">
            <i class="mdi-navigation-check"></i>
            <span>Next</span>
        </button>
        <button id="btnCloseContactInfoModel" class="btn-large btn-form-2 btn-floating waves-effect waves-light red darken-2 left" type="button">
            <i class="mdi-navigation-close"></i>
            <span >cancel</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just try the jquery code that you suggested but it doesnt work as well.The input that the users key in are come out in the textbox of email 1, 2, and 3 at the same time.But then what I want to do is when I key in the input for email 1, that input will be fill up in the textbox of email 1 only but not those 3 emails' textbox.

Comment: ,I just try the jquery code that you suggested but it doesnt work as well.The input that the users key in are come out in the textbox of email 1, 2, and 3 at the same time.But then what I want to do is when I key in the input for email 1, that input will be fill up in the textbox of email 1 only but not those 3 emails' textbox.

Comment: First thing, you have added readonly attribute for all the input box of your contact so your can't type in there. Now, when modal opens and you select any type from three types and enter some text.

So what you want here? if you select type 1 then entered text should go in email 1 and so on.. like that?

Comment: I've edited the answer as per your suggestions. Please check and let me know.

Comment: can I ask you one more question?how to show the input for "contacttype" and "contact" in separated row?

Comment: In your scenario, "contacttype" allows you to choose in which email address input box you want to put the text entered in "contact". So i didnt exactly get it, what you want to do ?

Comment: Sorry,actually the selection of insert the text in which email is for the user.It means that if the user click on the textbox of email 1,the user has the rights to choose type 2 / 3(not only for type 1 ).So, just now I just realize that your given answer is when the user choose the type 1,the text that the user key in will go in textbox of email 1.I think it is not I want.

Comment: If you select type 1 or 2 or 3 in the drop down then text entered in the "contact" will go in the email address input box number you have selected in the type. User has the rights to choose other options also.

Comment: I know what you mean.but I want is when the user select the type "2" in textbox of email 1,the text entered by the user will go in textbox of email 1 but not textbox of email 2.

Comment: That is want I want.Thanks for your help.Appreciate it.

Comment: any issues bro? why you have removed accepted answer?

Comment: Nothing, since I am worry my question involves some privacy issue of my institution, I wish to delete this post but failed. Anyway your answer is very helpful, thanks a lot